# Are there nerve endings on or inside the corpus cavernosum/spongiosum?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

The penile skin has many nerve endings, but what about the inner structure of the penis?

There are two dorsal nerves on either cavernosum. But it is unknown whether these nerves provide sensitivity to the corpus cavernosum/spongiosum externally or internal.

Comment: Asking a question that no one has answered *again* doesn't improve your chances of it being answered. Did you do any research on this? If you have, can you please edit to add to your question?

Comment: Cannot find information on this topic.